# How to find differences from two lists

Tags: python

Find the difference between two lists of integers in Python. The order doesn't matter.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
>>> list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
[]
```

Now add a new element to list b.

```
>>> b.append(1)
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1]
```

The new element is not considered in *difference*, perhaps because it is a repeated value

```
>>> list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
[]
>>> list(set(b).difference(set(a)))
[]
```

Add another, new value

```
>>> b.append(9)
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 9]

>>> list(set(b).difference(set(a)))
[9]
```

So how can I find the real difference between the 2 lists: elements not in both (the opposite of intersection I suppose)

```
list(set(a).mystery_func(set(b))
[1, 9]
```

Comment: A `set` will only consider the *unique* values in the list, hence the second `1` is ignored. You will need to create your own function; have a look at [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Further to @jonrsharpe's comment see https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset for the `set` docs

Comment: Please note that here this is not exactly a substraction.

I would use `print list(((cb-ca)+(ca-cb)).elements())` with ca and cb the counters of the lists a and b.

Comment: With set, another solution would probably to use sub-indices for repeating elements.

Comment: @user189 I am sorry but I do not understand the solution. What are subindicies?

Comment: for instance, if you transform [1, 1] into [(1, 1), (1, 2)] and [1] into [(1, 1)] (a sort could help, here), then the difference of the sets would probably be [(1, 2)], that you can easily transform back to [1].

Comment: And I would like to add that this is not a duplicate to me, since these answers do not appear in the other question and the answers of the other question do not exactly apply here (since this is not a simple substraction).

Comment: I agree, I have reviewed the other question's answers and it is not the same scenario. The decision to close the question was made before any answers could be placed. I would have liked to have seen an answer  (not in comments) from @user189 and jonrsharpe's comment would have also been a good answer if elaborated.

Comment: Not exactly 1 line: >>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(a)
>>> c
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
>>> d = Counter(b)
>>> d
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 9: 1})
>>> c - d
Counter()
>>> d - c
Counter({1: 1, 9: 1})